# how to cite legal cases in BibTeX

Tags: bibtex, citing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the proper way to cite a legal document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12209/what-is-the-proper-way-to-cite-a-legal-document)

Does anyone know the proper formatting for citing a legal case in BibTeX?  Say for example that I want to cite Brown v. Board of Education, 1954.  How would this look in BibTeX?

Comment: Legal citations really show the limits of traditional `bibtex`.  You are probably better trying to use `biber` and `biblatex`, for which some legal styles have been implemented (I believe).

Comment: There's just been some recent discussion of this here: [Bluebook support in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71306/2693) and the outlook seems pretty bleak.  See also [What is the proper way to cite a legal document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12209/2693).

Comment: Have you checked out the `camel` and `jurabib` packages? I'm not a legal scholar, so I must confess that I have no experience with either package.