# How can I remove the year label of the misc type in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, citing

I would like to remove the year label, if it is undefined. What I get:

> EC No 197/38 2012 (n.d.)

But it should be:

> EC No 197/38 2012

In the bibliography I get this, but it is correct for me:

> EC No 197/38 2012: Waste electrical and electronic equipment (WEEE), 4
>   July 2012, Commission Regulation.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@Misc{EC4July2012,
  Title                    = {Waste electrical and electronic equipment ({WEEE}), 4 July 2012},
  Author                   = {{EC No 197/38 2012}},
  Type                     = {Commission Regulation},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}
Something \autocite{EC4July2012}.
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: The proper way would be to have the date (in your 4 July 2012) case in the  `year` field in the `bibtex` entry.

Comment: @Guido The problem is that it is a European Comission Regulation. And in the short form citation should be "EC No 197/38 2012". The form and style of laws are difficult to make correct in this case.

Comment: If you have more of these rules/regulations/laws that need special handling, it might be a good idea to create a new entry type for those (a starting point might be [List of People analog to Bibliography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62995/35864) and [How can I create entirely new data types with BibLaTeX/Biber?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175776/35864)), if you can provide a prototype of what your citations contain and how they should look like in citations and bibliographies, we might be able to help you here.

Comment: Of course you can also just redefine a cite command to always omit dates for `@misc`s: `\renewbibmacro*{cite:labelyear+extrayear}{%
  \ifentrytype{misc}
    {}
    {\iffieldundef{labelyear}
      {}
      {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
       \printfield{labelyear}%
       \printfield{extrayear}}}}}` (modulo line breaks and comment characters, if you want that, I can write up an answer).

Comment: @moewe It is working with your redefinition, but now i have space before parenthesis in all cites. Author x and Author y ( 2014 ) or (Author y et. al. 2002 )?

Comment: I suppose that is thanks to white-space not being properly commented out, in the above code you should insert line brakes at the points marked with "\n" in this code snippet: `\renewbibmacro*{cite:labelyear+extrayear}{%`\n
  `\ifentrytype{misc}`\n
    `{}`\n
    `{\iffieldundef{labelyear}`\n
      `{}`\n
      `{\printtext[bibhyperref]{%`\n
       `\printfield{labelyear}%`\n
       `\printfield{extrayear}}}}}`\n` and nowhere else

Comment: @moewe I guess by now you know what i am asking for ;-)

Comment: @Johannes_B Your wish is my (very late) command.

Answer (score 2):

Handling of laws, regulations etc. that are supposed to be cited in a very particular way isn't all that easy. If you have several of such documents you might want to consider creating dedicated entrytypes for easy customisation (see [How can I create entirely new data types with BibLaTeX/Biber?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175776/35864) on how to do that, and [How to implement a jurisdiction biblatex entry type?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/76248/35864) & [How to cite a section of a Constitution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/132963/35864) for a more thought through and an ad-hoc solution; as well as [What is the proper way to cite a legal document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12209/35864) for a general discussion).

In your case, there is the obvious ad-hoc solution of suppressing years for `@misc`s:

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite:labelyear+extrayear}{%
  \ifentrytype{misc}
    {}
    {\iffieldundef{labelyear}
      {}
      {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
         \printfield{labelyear}
         \printfield{extrayear}}}}}
```